# Class.forName in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I am using SQL server 2008 as a Database. And using **JDBC**, I am accessing the DB as Under.

```
public class DBConn {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{

    Connection con =null;
    //Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://BG4WS0552:1433;databaseName=DynamicsAx2009",
            "TESTUSER", "Sonata@123");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM custtable";
    DatabaseMetaData dmd = con.getMetaData();
    ResultSet rs = dmd.getColumns ("DynamicsAx2009", "%", "custtable", null) ;
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    int i = 1;
    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.print(i++ + " COLUMN_NAME is " + rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME"));
        System.out.print(" TYPE:" + rs.getString("TYPE_NAME"));

        System.out.println("  DATA_TYPE is " + rs.getString("DATA_TYPE"));
    }
}}
```

See in above code, i have commented out that Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"). Even though my program is running fine. Please let me know how it is working without registering the driver.

Comment: I'm using the mssql-jdbc-8.2.2.jre8.jar driver, and it would not load without the Class.forName call. Perhaps this depends on the vendor whether we are free to omit the call or not.

Answer (score 3):

Since JDBC 4.0 drivers should declare their implementations of `java.sql.Driver` by listing all their implementations in `/META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver`. The `DriverManager` will automatically load and register all drivers that declare themselves that way using [java.util.ServiceLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html).

This removes the need to use `Class.forName()` (or the system property `jdbc.drivers`) to load driver(s), as long as the driver is JDBC 4.0 compliant.

Answer (score 1):

The Class.forName call should not really be necessary with modern JDBC drivers anymore. If those are properly installed, they register themselves (using the jar file services manifest).

But better to have the code, in case that did not work.